# Disable sharing of file in 2016

Tags: 2016, sharing

I work in a school and we just moved from a VLE to SharePoint 2016,

Is there away of stopping students from sharing there work in there mysite/Ondrive?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article:
http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2014/11/managing-sharing-access-requests-sharepoint-site/

BR,
Björn

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)